# display nested JSON in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I believe this is going to be an easy fix but everything I'm trying isn't working.

I'm getting data from an external API and I'm looking at display the data after matching the ids.

The data is JSON and has some nested content.

I've tried the following

```rb
<li>Street: <%= @users.find{|u| u['id'] == @album['userId']}.try(:[],'address''street') || 'not available' %></li>
```

The data is structured like so

```
{
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want that to be:

```
<li>Street: <%= @users.find{|u| u['id'] == @album['userId']}.try(:[],'address').try(:[],'street') || 'not available' %></li>
```

For a multi-level `try`, you might want to look into `dig`.

Also, if the iteration is as in your previous questions, then `@album` may need to be `album`. If this is in a different context than your previous questions, then kindly disregard.

Answer (score 0):

This is where `dig` is useful:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html

```
<li>Street: <%= @users.find{|u| u['id'] == @album['userId']}.dig(:address, :street)  || 'not available' %></li>
```